# Getting US Xbox Live games in europe

Tags: xbox-live-arcade

I am desperately trying to find Flotilla on XBLA Europe. I had a look in all games under "F", and I looked for it with the search option but without any success. Any idea how I could get it anyway? Is it possible to buy XBLA games on CD? Or to get a US account just to buy a game and then switch back to my normal account?

Comment: Did you try looking for [Flotilla via the marketplace website](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-GB/Product/Flotilla/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8025855048b?cid=search)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create a new, American Live account. Create an American account with Hotmail or Live. I say create new because you won't be able to change your country if you already have a UK Hotmail account. I had the same issue, so I created a new account with "Location: US", used my credit card, and it worked. Any major credit card should work when purchasing points. If you can't use your credit card, you can always buy a points card from Amazon (or elsewhere) and redeem the card's code on your account.

The drawback here is that all the stuff you in your previous account needs to be re-bought and there is no way to transfer that ownership. However, the XBLA and other downloaded games should be accessible from the new account if you are using the same Xbox 360.

Comment: its working. But you cant do it with the credit card, because the billing information need to be in the US and this is not my case.

Comment: Amazon does not deliver points per email to the non US, pcgamesupply.com does. Just provide a valid phone number, they to a order verification by phone.

Comment: its even better on play-asia.com. They deliver it instantly without any verification

Answer (score 1):

You can make an American account, with a hotmail account that says it's American. I'm not sure if you have to pay with an American credit card, or if you have to buy an American MS Points card to buy, but it's worth trying.

Comment: As visible on Maximus cards (http://www.maximuscards.com/itempage.php?cat=1) there are distinct Microsoft point types for different geographical locations. Also, the real question is whether a game downloaded on the American account will play nice on the default account (on the PS3 it's a non-issue, but that doesn't really help in this case).